# Select the FIRST record with a value greater than XXX

Tags: sql

OK, another newbie SQL question which i'm sure has a simple solution and i'll kick myself when someone posts the answer!

I have two tables as follows

```
PRICE_DTA
PRC_DATE    PRC_TIME    PRC_PRICE    PRC_ITEM

2008-01-01  06.00.00    1.05        JUMPER
2008-01-01  09.00.00    1.20        JUMPER
2008-01-25  17.00.00    1.75        JUMPER
2008-01-02  09.00.00    2.25        TROUSERS
2008-10-25  12.00.00    2.95        TROUSERS 


SALE_DTA
TRN_DATE    TRN_TIME    TRN_PRICE_PAID   TRN_ITEM

2008-01-01  08.30.00                     JUMPER
2008-01-03  10.00.00                     JUMPER
2008-01-03  17.00.00                     JUMPER
2008-01-01  13.00.00                     TROUSERS
2008-01-02  09.00.00                     TROUSERS
```

The way the prices work is that you get the NEXT available price(prices aren't set until after the purchase because we bulk all the orders up and get a cheaper price the more we buy in one go). So, in the example the 08.30.00 purchase on 2008-01-01 will have been for 1.20 because that is the first available price after the purchase date/time

So, I need to populate the prices in the SALE_DTA table using the TRN_DATE/TRN_TIME fields to go an get the next available price off the PRICE_DTA tables. NOTE: The DATE and TIME fields on both tables are CHAR fields not date/timestamp fields

I can concatenate the date and time easily enough but i'm not sure how to find the FIRST record on PRICE_DTA with a date/time stamp greater than that. I know on UNISYS DMS II I can use a 'FIND NEXT GREATER THAN' but can't find a similar command in SQL?

I'm happy to create a temporary table as part of the solution if that makes it simpler.

Comment: Can't you use a `DATETIME` field instead ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  UPDATE statement syntax may vary somewhat by vendor when joining data from other tables...

Comment: It's a DB2 table on an AS/400 machine. Unfortunately, I didn't design the DB so although DATETIME may make it easier I can't change that as the tables are supplied by our client

Comment: What are the primary keys of the tables? `Date`, `Time` and `Item`?

Comment: The unique key for PRICE_DTA is DATE, TIME, PRICE. For SALE_DTA there is an additional field I haven't included as I didn't think it was relevant called TRN_ID which is a unique sequential numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic SQL solution for this can be done with a couple of joins:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO - Pick appropriate columns
FROM
    SALE_DTA s
       INNER JOIN
    PRICE_DTA p
       ON
          p.PRC_ITEM = s.TRN_ITEM and
          (p.PRC_DATE > s.TRN_DATE or
              (p.PRC_DATE = s.TRN_DATE and
              p.PRC_TIME > s.TRN_TIME
          ))
       LEFT JOIN
    PRICE_DTA p2
       ON
          p2.PRC_ITEM = s.TRN_ITEM and
          (p2.PRC_DATE > s.TRN_DATE or
              (p2.PRC_DATE = s.TRN_DATE and
              p2.PRC_TIME > s.TRN_TIME
          )) and
          (p2.PRC_DATE < p.PRC_DATE or
              (p2.PRC_DATE = p.PRC_DATE and
               p2.PRC_TIME < p.PRC_TIME
          ))
 WHERE
     p2.PRC_ITEM IS NULL
```

Hopefully, you can see the logic here. The `INNER JOIN` is used to match rows in `SALE_DTA` with *all* rows in `PRICE_DTA` that occur afterwards. We then do a second join (the `LEFT JOIN`) to this `PRICE_DTA` again, this time trying to locate a row with this join (`p2`) such that it still occurs after the `s` date/time, but occurs *before* the `p` date/time.

Finally, in the `WHERE` clause, we eliminate any rows where this `LEFT JOIN` actually succeeded. Therefore, by deduction, we know that the row that we matched in `p` is the *earliest* row from `PRICE_DTA` which occurs after the `SALE_DTA` date/time.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly get the data required but DB2 don't support `JOIN` with `UPDATE` statement. So you can take a different route like

Create a auxiliary table

```
create table SALE_DTA_temp(TRN_DATE,TRN_TIME,TRN_PRICE_PAID,TRN_ITEM)
```

Do a insert into temp table from the query

```
insert into SALE_DTA_temp
select sd.TRN_DATE,
sd.TRN_TIME,
tab.max_PRC_PRICE as TRN_PRICE_PAID,
sd.TRN_ITEM
from SALE_DTA sd
join 
(
select PRC_DATE, max(PRC_PRICE) as max_PRC_PRICE
from PRICE_DTA
group by PRC_DATE
) tab on sd.TRN_DATE = tab.PRC_DATE
```

Drop the old table

```
drop table SALE_DTA
```

Rename the table

```
RENAME TABLE SALE_DTA_temp TO SALE_DTA
```