# How can I make a Vlookup like SQL query?

Tags: sql

There are multiple SO questions and external blogs showing examples how to make an SQL JOIN query *identical* to an Excel VLOOKUP function (=vlookup(value, range, column, FALSE) type). That is easy.
My problem is that I would like a solution *similar* to VLOOKUP, or more precisely a function like =vlookup(value, range, column, TRUE). The difference is that in this version if *value* is not found in the data range then the last smaller value is returned (as the *range* must be sorted). I want to do this, or even better to return not the last smaller but the first larger value in case the value is not present (by changing the sign if *value* is a number it is easy to change). Ideally the solution should be for both versions (like a <= vs. a >= operator to change which neighbour to pick if the exact value is missing).
I found a great SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912403/select-the-first-record-with-a-value-greater-than-xxx) that solves it through double JOIN statement. It can also be changed to do >, >= or <= versions. The only problem that for larger databases, due to the second JOIN, where two large subsets are joined, it is very slow. Actually for me it runs hours. Even taking the tables outside of SQL and write a small program is faster.
I was wondering, if this is doable through a Stored procedure, or similar, to make it much faster?
I use MySQL, but would be interested in any SQL dialect.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  base_table AS b
LATERAL CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT
    l.column
  FROM
    lookup_table AS l
  WHERE
        l.some_key  = b.some_key
    AND l.some_val >= b.some_val
  ORDER BY
    l.some_val
  LIMIT
    1
)
  AS v
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  b.*,
  (
    SELECT
      l.column
    FROM
      lookup_table AS l
    WHERE
          l.some_key  = b.some_key
      AND l.some_val >= b.some_val
    ORDER BY
      l.some_val
    LIMIT
      1
  ) 
FROM
  base_table AS b
```

The lookup table should have an index on `(some_key, some_val, column)`

Comment: Great, thanks. I could make the second run, and it works great. On a smaller test database, your solution ran in 0.26 s, while the other solution I linked was 3 MINUTES and 30s. On the whole database your was 33 s, while the old one I could not wait enough.